# How can you play a sound to work on all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, audio, chat

I am currently designing a chatting system. How can I have a sound play (like a popping noise)  when a message is received that is cross browser compatible? Is there such a thing? I want to have a similar noise/time of noise to Facebook.

Comment: Open this link it will solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483455/play-sound-when-message-received

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<audio>` tag is a good HTML5 way of playing sound, but suffers from two drawbacks:

1. It won't work with older web browsers
2. Not all web browsers support all audio formats

To get around the audio format problem, we can put multiple versions of the sound in a way that will cause web browsers which don't support one version to skip forward to the next:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  <source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  Sorry, your web browser does not support sound.
</audio>
```

There are libraries which make this process easier and give you more control. [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org) is one, which gives good cross-browser support including older browsers which do not support the `<audio` tag via Flash fallback.

Answer (score 3):

I find sound manager to be the best cross browser solution: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/